# XML file in HTML page

Tags: xml

I am trying to load an xml file that is on my local system.I have url as my local path.
But am getting error..

This is my code:i have used local path.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script>
 function loadXMLDoc(url)
 {alert(url);
 var xmlhttp;
  var txt,x,xx,i;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
 else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    txt="<table border='1'><tr><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th></tr>";
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("CD");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      txt=txt + "<tr>";
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
          }
        }
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
          }
        }
      txt=txt + "</tr>";
      }
    txt=txt + "</table>";
    document.getElementById('txtCDInfo').innerHTML=txt;
    }
  }

 xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="txtCDInfo">
 <button onclick="loadXMLDoc('file:///E:/file.xml')">Get CD info</button>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I have local xml file in my E path.
can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to access filesystems with XMLHttpRequest, security restrictions prevent it in most browsers. Run an HTTP server and use it to fetch both the HTML document and anything you want to read with XHR.

Comment: can u pls explain with example..I am new to this..i cant understand

Comment: Make your URL `http://something/something/something` instead of `c:\documents\sites\something\something\something`